# perform other functions when data is received from the server in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to do perform other javascript functions after the data is received from the server (in reality, it is only an insert statement). the alert() statement is not performed and I'm not sure if ajaxRequest.responseText is needed to perform statements, with the code given:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('confirmation');
    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    //perform other javascript functions (modal confirmation)
    alert("Success");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, open your developer tools with F12 and search for the error message.

Comment: there are no errors being displayed, the query (insert statement) is being executed correctly but I need to perform statements in the javascript after the execution of the php code (say modal confirmation callings)

Comment: You need to perform statements in the javascript? What does that mean? Do you mean functions?

Comment: yes, I need to show modal confirmation as well as clear form elements without reloading the page

Comment: "without reloading the page" does your page reload right now?

Comment: nope, the insert into statement in a separate php file is being executed correctly, but when returning to the ajax function, I cannot perform other script statements